Is it possible to directly populate a recursive entity that contains a list of itself with Entity Framework?
This is the error I get:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cycle detected while auto-including navigations: 'SimpleTask.Subtasks'. To fix this issue, either don't configure at least one navigation in the cycle as auto included in OnModelCreating or call 'IgnoreAutoInclude' method on the query.

This is my entity:
public class SimpleTask 
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? fatherTaskId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SimpleTask> Subtasks{ get; set; } = new List<SimpleTask>();
}

This is the context:
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SimpleTask>()
                    .Navigation(t => t.Subtasks)
                    .AutoInclude();
    }

    public DbSet<SimpleTask> SimpleTasks { get; set; }
}

Is it possible with a select in a single task full it with iteration using AutoInclude()?
I thought the problem was generate to object SimpleTask FatherTask but the problem persist.
What am I doing wrong?

Your configuration mentions "SubTasks" but your entity mentions "ChildTask" Ensure your example is correct and complete enough to be able to reproduce the issue you are trying to solve. Mechanics can't fix the funny noise your minivan is making when you bring your hatchback into the garage.

I use the "keys" / entity id's to maintain (serialize / deserialize) recursive structures. Then at run time, I make a pass over the "structure" and resolve all the id's into references. This is an app where the entire "data model" is in memory at all times.

How is your ChildTask defined? Are there any other navigation properties?

What you ask is a bad idea that could end up loading 1 item or an entire 100K table in memory. There's no way to come up with an efficient implementation without knowing exactly how the table is designed either, whether it has a hierarchyId or path-like column, whether a recursive CTE is needed.  EF will reconstruct the hierarchy if the query itself loads all the necessary objects

EF Core 8 does allow hierarchical queries using hierarchyid in a far more powerful way

BTW if you want to load the entire table in a hierarchical way, you can just load all the entities and EF will reconstruct the relations.

What you ask is not supported, for a reason. The case is described in EF issue 34198. See this comment:

You cannot know the depth of your hierarchy unless you look into the database for the specific record. Thus there is no "simple" option to write a SQL statement to let the database handle it.

In other words, querying contexts.SimpleTasks triggers a query of undefined depth in a hierarchy of SimpleTasks. In theory, this could fetch an incredible amount of data and take ages to finish. It's telling that there is no standard SQL statement to accomplish this. It would require a recursive query, the implementation of which would differ among database engines.
Of course EF could choose to support auto-included self-references. So far, they just don't. You could try your luck and revive the change request. I don't expect it to be honored.

It's important that roji, the maintainer of NpgSQL is involved in that discussion. How could EF load a hierarchy automagically in every database? It can't go loading entities one by one. In SQL Server the best answer would be to use the proprietary hierarchyid type. In PostgreSQL, the equivalent is the ltree extension. In other databases path-like columns are the fastest way for some types of queries. Recursive CTEs are universal but slower than an indexed tree/hierarchy type.

I just thought of another critical problem - cyclical references. If EF was to load descendants one by one, it would have to detect cyclical references to avoid infinite queries.
